python-asyncua get monitored items for subscription
when using python-opcua - Clent class I could read the _monitored_items_map attribute from the subscription object to get a list of the monitored items in that subscription:
items = sub._monitoreditems_map

in python-asyncua the subscription object doesn't have the _monitored_items_map attribute. How can I get this information now? Do I need to read it from the server?

The subscription object has a dict _monitored_items
You could do this, to get all monitored items:
subscriped_nodes: List[ua.Node] = [i.node for i in sub._monitored_items.values()]

